# Why was tracker desktop search removed?

Tags: tracker

I remember a release when tracker was one of the innovations of Ubuntu. What happened to it?

Comment: Sorry, what tracker? Torrents? Bug reporting?

Comment: @Lekensteyn: most probably this: http://projects.gnome.org/tracker/

Comment: "Innovation" is overrated term here, as for example Spotlight has existed in Mac OS X for much longer, and Tracker is direct copy of that.

Comment: @Olli I don't mean innovation compared to other SO, but in the ubuntu life.

Comment: see also [11.04 - Is anyone aware of any progress made in packing updated versions of tracker (desktop search tool)? - Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34127/is-anyone-aware-of-any-progress-made-in-packing-updated-versions-of-tracker-des)

Answer (score 3):

[Metatracker](http://projects.gnome.org/tracker/), usually referred to as Tracker, was introduced in 8.04 (an LTS release), but removed, I believe, in 9.04.  I can only speculate as to why it was removed, but my guess would be multiple bugs, such as 100% CPU when the tracker daemon failed, or the slow start up on less powerful systems due to the indices updating.

I run it on my system and haven't noticed any slow downs, but my laptop is reasonably powerful.

Comment: That seems like a nice link, but it isn't a link to wikipedia, but to wikinfo.  *Wikinfo differs in editorial policy from Wikipedia. Generally, the main article on a subject should present the subject in a positive light or as a concept which makes sense. Alternative or critical perspectives should be placed in linked articles, Wikinfo welcomes editors from Wikipedia and offers much more opportunity to edit freely. Original research and original ideas are welcome.*

Comment: Ah yeah.  I didn't notice that.  I don't think the editing policy particularly detracts from the content of that article though, so I'll leave the link intact, edit the source.

Comment: @Scaine now link is dead :/.

Comment: Thanks - removed the link and will try a search for a better comparison.