# How can I install metatracker from source?

Tags: install-from-source, tracker

Following a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34127/is-anyone-aware-of-any-progress-made-in-packing-updated-versions-of-tracker-desk) I raised a few weeks back, I would like to install tracker and see how it works with natty. The latest [stable release](http://projects.gnome.org/tracker/download.html) of metatracker is 0.10.10, but unfortunately, only version 0.8.17 can be found packaged.
Does anyone know how can I install tracker from source, and if anybody has already tried it, please let me know how well does it work with natty.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Tracker 0.9.26 from their [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~tracker-team/+archive/tracker-unstable). There is also a stable PPA, but there's nothing for 11.04 there yet.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but if you look on the right (of the page), it seems that this latest upload to the PPA even fails to build...

Comment: You are right, indeed. I installed _something_from there, but was stumped as to how to start the thing (running Unity)...